# Choosing country projections

Tags: coordinate-system

Anyone know of a good reference (either pay or open-web) that details recommended country projections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset](http://www.epsg-registry.org) which is more up-to-date and where epsg.io got its information.

Admittedly, it doesn't always have projected coordinate reference systems that are suitable for an entire country--but only because no one's told us what is used for a map of the entire country!

[Spatial Reference](http://spatialreference.org) allows user-contributions so might have more information.

Disclosure: I'm on the subcommittee that maintains it.

Comment: Is there a way to import  projection info from either site into ArcGIS projection.

Comment: If the definition isn't already in your ArcGIS installation, you could ask here (or GeoNet) if a later release has it, and if so, what's the WKT. Otherwise, define it in ArcMap and add it to your Favorites for later use.

Answer (score 3):

Try [epsg.io](http://epsg.io).  You can type in the name of a country or even search by CRS.  And it is free!  Type in the country or region you need a projection for and it will return the recommended coordinate system.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a source called [Coordinate Reference Systems (CRS) of European Countries](http://www.crs-geo.eu/crs-national.htm)
*URL:* http://www.crs-geo.eu/crs-national.htm

It contains

- descriptions of Coordinate Reference Systems
- transformation parameters to pan-European CRS ETRS89, EVRF2000 and EVRF2007
- verification data for transformation
- online-transformation of single points for position and height from national CRS of a country to pan-European CRS ETRS89, EVRF2000 and EVRF2007 for test and verification purposes

To get the information select a country in the list or click on the corresponding red dot in the map

[image: Europe_map]

Answer (score 0):

Try http://projectionwizard.org/ which will allow you to define your area of interest and the distortion property you wish to conserve. It will then give you a suggestion of suitable projections. You can copy the prog.4 text or if you are an arcMap user, you can pick similar projections, then edit pre-defined coordinate systems to change the standard parallels and center of origins to approximate the recommendation.